# How to back-up only my commits?

Tags: git

How would I produce an archive of the commits I made - reachable from `master` - to a repository in Git? The format produced by `git format-patch` would work.

(Context: I'm finishing as a contractor on a projector due to it not being a good fit, and I've already had one client not pay me for my last invoice due to sketchy terms in my freelancing agency's contract, so I'd like to have some receipts of having actually done work if push comes to shove.)

Comment: If you clone the repository you'd have the full history, including your own commits. Is there a reason not to have those by other people?

Comment: @OliverRadini To avoid trouble over exfiltrating too much data I have no copyrights to - I own all unpaid for output so I'd like to only stick to that - and because the repo is fairly huge.

Comment: That is, I'm fundamentally uninterested in doing something that could be construed as harming the client, I just don't want to end up with no paper trail in case they start to act in bad faith.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git log --all -p --author="<your user>" > test.log
```

Should get the log of changes into a file.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about the `-p` option to log. This seems perfect for what I want it for.

Answer (score 1):

```
for commit in $(git log --all --author="email-address" --pretty=format:"%h");
do
        git format-patch $commit -1
done
```

This will generate patches for your commits.

Answer (score 1):

Use [git bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle). Create a bundle for a range of commits:

```
git bundle create update.bundle HEAD~5..HEAD
```

To restore the commits use `git fetch` or `git pull`:

```
git pull update.bundle master
```